# When passing base class into an constructor expecting derived, why do both of them destroy themselves?

Tags: c++

I understand that you can't expect to have a derived reference pointing at its base class because it will lose functionality, but I was curious on what would actually happen to understand more about the sequence of events.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base() { std::cout << "Base constructor" << std::endl; }
    Base(const Base&) { std::cout << "Base copy constructor" << std::endl; } 
    ~Base() { std::cout << "Base destructor" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived(const Base& b) : Base(b) {  std::cout << "Derived constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~Derived() { std::cout << "Derived destructor" << std::endl; }
};


struct OwnsDerived
{
    OwnsDerived(const Derived& derivedObject) : derivedRef(derivedObject) { std::cout << "OwnsDerived created..." << std::endl; }

    const Derived& derivedRef;
};


int main () {
    std::cout << "Main starts: " << std::endl;
    const Base b;

    std::cout << "\nMain creating object that owns a reference to derived: " << std::endl;
    OwnsDerived s(b);

    std::cout << "\nMain ends: " << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

The result I got was:

```
Main starts: 
Base constructor

Main creating object that owns a reference to derived: 
Base copy constructor  
Derived constructor   <-- why is a derived trying to be created when passing the wrong type in the constructor
OwnsDerived created...
Derived destructor   //<-- these are treated as temporaries 
Base destructor      //<--

Main ends: 
Base destructor
```

Even when I change the reference to be a copy of the object instead, it behaves similarly, which is also surprising to me.

I would really appreciate any pointers or any resources to learn about the more nuanced mechanics of these constructor/destructors!

Comment: Can't reproduce.   Building with g++ results in three destructor calls after "Main ends:".  That is what I expect on visual examination of your code.    I suspect the problem is with building (e.g. you are running a version of your executable that predates the code).    Delete all object files and executables (or do a `"build clean", if your IDE supports that) then rebuild the entire program.

Comment: Sorry, let me put everything in, but my main concern is the Derived and Base destructor call right before "main ends".

I realized after digging more that my question has nothing to do with base/derived classes, but more toward why OwnsDerived's constructor would create a temporary Derived object if an object of a different type is passed in (and later destroy the temporary Derived object)

If I pass in Derived as it expects, then everything's perfect.

Comment: Delegating constructors require c++11 (or greater) check your compilation switches.

Comment: `OwnsDerived` doesn't own a `Derived`, it merely references one (and presumably is only useable within the lifetime of that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OwnsDerived` constructor takes a `Derived` by reference to const, but you pass a `Base` instance. So, the compiler will try to convert the `Base` instance to a `Derived`. That's possible by calling the (implicit) conversion constructor in `Derived`. So, a temporary instance of `Derived` is created.

To fix the implicit conversion, declare the `Derived` constructor as [`explicit`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#explicit-ctors).

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
    explicit Derived(const Base& b);
    //...
};
```

Comment: Or not have that constructor *at all*

Comment: Got it, thanks! The implicit conversion is what caused the constructor of Derived to be called and goes out of scope when the constructor of OwnsDerived (incorrectly named since it's a reference to Derived) is done. 

Although I am just wondering how this implicit conversion is done without any warnings/errors when it's possible the two types are completely unrelated/unconvertible (I just tried it by making Derived its own class). That was why I wasn't even aware of this happening at all under the hood.

Comment: @StillLearning That's why you should almost never declare implicit conversions.

Answer (score -1):

Reference to this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm
In CPP when ever you call a function, it will copy the paramenter of that function instead of using it directly

So, when you call the contructor of `OwnsDerived` it use `const Base b` as it paramenter. The system will copy this to other memory where you get this log `Base copy constructor`. I will call this a `copied_b`. So `copied_b` is `Base` it will convert it to `Derive` as the contructor of `OwnsDerived` required a `Derive` so there is `Derived constructor`. I call this `derived_of_copied_b`. At the end of the contructor of `OwnsDerived` both `copied_b` and `derived_of_copied_b` will be destroy, where you will see `Derived destructor` and `Base destructor` right after `OwnsDerived created...`.

I wish this could explain your question.